# How can I remap End/Home keys in Keynote?

Tags: keyboard, keynote, keybindings

I use an external keyboard, and I'm used to using End/Home to move to the end/start of the line, respectively.
However, when typing text in Keynotes, pressing End/Home moves me to the last/first slide, which is confusing (and annoying, I'm afraid).

Is there anything wrong with my setup? Can I alter this in any way?

Note: I'm using:

```
❯ cat ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict
{
"\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfLine:"; /* Home */
"\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfLine:"; /* End */
"$\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:"; /* Shift + Home */
"$\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:"; /* Shift + End */
"^\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfDocument:"; /* Ctrl + Home */
"^\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfDocument:"; /* Ctrl + End */
"$^\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfDocumentAndModifySelection:"; /* Shift + Ctrl + Home */
"$^\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfDocumentAndModifySelection:"; /* Shift + Ctrl + End */
}
```